# Code Igniter File Upload For Autocad

Tags: codeigniter

Anyone could help me ? Why dwg extension is read as not allowed types file, while I had write in `mimes.php` to include `dwg` extension file as allowed file extension..

Comment: does it work if you set `$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; `

Comment: It works correctly, but I have to not allowed types of .exe too, so I decided to type file .dwg in mimes.php. There is another way to set not allowed type of file of data rather than I have to type very much of type of data in allowed types of data in $config['allowed_types'] = ' '; ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to the MIME array located at `root/application/config/mimes.php`

```
array(
  'dwg' => array('application/acad', 'application/x-acad', 'application/autocad_dwg', 'image/x-dwg', 'application/dwg', 'application/x-dwg', 'application/x-autocad', 'image/vnd.dwg', 'drawing/dwg')
);
```

These are simply all the possible MIME types for a `.dwg` file.

Now when you are using the file uploading class you can simply add `dwg` to the array of allowed file types

```
$this->load->library('upload', array(
  'allowed_types' => 'dwg'
));
```